# Structuring CakePHP Views

Tags: php, cakephp, view, structure

Long time reader, first time poster :)

I'm just embarking on my first Cake app so hopefully you guys can help me on my way.

First question is about extending/including views. I realise the way the layouts/view work is to prevent code having to be repeated, but I can't get my head around how to set up what I want to do without some repetition.

My page layout consists, apart from header and footer, a left nav bar which I want Controllers to add themselves to if appropriate, and a top nav bar which will be populated by appropriate pages within the current controller.

I tried creating a view block from within the controller but it didn't work, I'm a bit stumped.

Here's what I have:

My default layout includes the sidebar, currently just hardcoded, and the content:

```
Layout default.ctp

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>.....</head>
<body>
...

<div id='leftnav'>
This is where I want my left nav
I want controllers to be able to add themselves
here.
</div>


<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Then my /Customer/index view:

```
View index.ctp

<?php $this->extend('common'); ?>

<h1>Customers</h1>

.... do stuff with customers .....
```

Which extends my /Customer/common view to bring in the top nav bar, each view has to include this extend line, it would be nice not to have to if there's a different way of doing this.

At the moment, the links are just fixed but I'd like the controller to be able to create these options.

```
View common.ctp

<?php 
echo $this->Html->Link('index', "index")." ";
echo $this->Html->Link('find', 'find')." ";
echo $this->Html->Link('add', 'add')." ";
echo $this->Html->Link('details', 'details');

echo $this->Session->flash();

echo $this->fetch('content');

?>
```

Appreciate your help cheers! :D

Comment: Where is your attempt at View Blocks?  As the book mentions, "...blocks are ideal for implementing things such as sidebars...".  So - you're on the right track, but we'd need to see your code to offer suggestions/fixes, as opposed to writing your code for you.

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't want you to write it for me because then I don't know for next time :)  
  
I can create a view block from within a view, but not from within a controller. So if I wanted my top nav to contain generated links, I'd have to generate the block in each view so I'm sure that's not the way to achieve this.

Comment: How about using different layouts? Just use one for pages that include sidebar and the other for pages that not and set which layout to use in controller.

Comment: The sidebar will always be there.

Comment: How about passing the link list to the view from the controller, and creating an element that makes the nav bar. Then include this in the layout where required?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to put those links in your layout file. But you may have to re-write them as "$this->Html->link("Index",array("controller => $controller","action" => "index");" etc.

To get the current controller within the layout file you can say "$controller = $this->params['controller']".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have found a use for $this->params it came in handy for something else :)

Answer (score 0):

right, after searching around I think I found a good way of doing at least one of these things.

For the top nav, where the links will be populated by the controller, I'll pass an array from the controller to view. Then, instead of having an ->extend in every view I'll create an element to turn the array into a nav bar, and ->fetch this in the layout.

This leads me onto my next question....
[How much code is ok in a CakePHP Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224845/how-much-code-is-ok-in-a-cakephp-layout)

Comment: I edited this answer to actually answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Cake PHP HTML Helper
https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links

```
echo $this->Html->link('Users List', ['controller' => 'Users','action' => 'index']);
```

Output will be look like this:

```
<a href="/users/index">Users List</a>
```